# How do I show an image having it's path?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display an image having it's absolute path. I came upon this code on stackoverflow which should theoretically work, however I get error `Bitmap too big to be uploaded into a texture` on most images so I'm looking for another way to do it. Surprisingly there aren't any examples apart from this one on how to do it.

This is what I am trying:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);                  
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
layout.addView(image);
```

By the way the images I'm working with have been taken with the default camera app so they don't have any uncommon format or size (and can be seen with no problem on the gallery app). How can I add them to my layout?

Comment: Try this: image.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to resize your image first by using below code and then set it into the `ImageView`:

> ```
>  public static Drawable GetDrawable(String newFileName)
> {
>     File f;
>     BitmapFactory.Options o2;
>     Bitmap drawImage = null;
>     Drawable d = null;
>     try
>     {           
>         f = new File(newFileName);          
>         //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
>         //Decode image size
>         BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>         o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;            
>         o.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];          
>         BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);            
>         //The new size we want to scale to
>         final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;          
>         //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
>         int scale = 1;
>         while ((o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) && (o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE))
>             scale *= 2;         
>         //Decode with inSampleSize
>         o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
>         o2.inSampleSize = scale;            
>         drawImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
>         //Bitmap bmp = pictureDrawableToBitmap((PictureDrawable) drawable);         
>         d = new BitmapDrawable(drawImage);
>         //drawImage.recycle();
>         //new BitmapWorkerTask          
>     }
>     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
>     {
>     }
>     return d;
> }
> ```

Use the above method as below:

> imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: I'll try it on a few hours. I plan to implement pinch to zoom after I do this, will it be possible with this implementation? Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible with this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a smaller sample size (`inSampleSize`) that fits the heap

First, create a bitmap that fits the heap, possibly slightly larger than the one you require

```
BitmapFactory.Options bounds = new BitmapFactory.Options();
this.bounds.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, bounds);
if (bounds.outWidth == -1) { // TODO: Error }
int width = bounds.outWidth;
int height = bounds.outHeight;
boolean withinBounds = width <= maxWidth && height <= maxHeight;
if (!withinBounds) {
    int newWidth = calculateNewWidth(int width, int height);
    float sampleSizeF = (float) width / (float) newWidth;
    int sampleSize = Math.round(sampleSizeF);
    BitmapFactory.Options resample = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    resample.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, resample);
}
```

The second step is to call Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() to create a new bitmap to the exact resolution you require.

Make sure you clean up after the temporary bitmap to reclaim its memory. (Either let the variable go out of scope and let the GC deal with it, or call .recycle() on it if you are loading lots of images and are running tight on memory.)

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. I plan to implement pinch to zoom after I manage to do this. Will this implementation allow it?

Comment: I would say the two are independent. 
For pinch to zoom you might want to look at a imageView implementation on github which allows zoom easily.

Comment: I tried the code but I'm getting an error on the second line: `bounds cannot be resolved or is not a field` I tried replacing this. with context. but I get the same error